# Why doesn't it generate the consecutive numbers in MongoDB fields with Project Reactor?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Good morning, I'm taking a reactive programming course with Webflux. I wanted to modify the provided example by adding a field called 'consecutivo' (consecutive). I noticed that MongoDB doesn't have built-in consecutive values, so I need to generate them using a collection to store the last consecutive value.

I have two collections: 'products' (products) and 'products_counter' (product counter).

In the first collection, I store some simple data about products, and in the second collection, I store the consecutive value.

I'm working with Webflux using Reactor.

I have the following code inside a 'run' method, which is for testing purposes. That's why I'm deleting and recreating the collections every time the application starts.

```
mongoTemplate.dropCollection("products_counter").subscribe();
        ProductsCounter cp0 = new ProductsCounter ();
        cp0.setConsecutive(0L);
        mongoTemplate.insert(cp0, "products_counter").subscribe();

        mongoTemplate.dropCollection("products")
                .thenMany(Flux.just(new Product("TV Panasonic Screen LCD", 459.89),
                        new Product("Sony Camera HD Digital", 177.89),
                        new Product("Apple iPod", 46.89),
                        new Product("Sony Notebook", 846.89)))
                .flatMap(p -> {
                    return counterDao.findAll()
                            .take(1)
                            .singleOrEmpty()
                            .flatMap(cp1 -> {
                                Long consecutive = cp1.getConsecutive();
                                p.setCreateAt(new Date());
                                consecutive = consecutive + 1;
                                p.setConsecutive(consecutive);
                                cp1.setConsecutive(consecutive);
                                return counterDao.save(cp1)
                                        .then(productDao.save(p))
                                        .thenReturn(p);
                            });
                })
                .subscribe(savedProduct -> {
                    log.info("Id: " + savedProduct.getId() + " Product: " + savedProduct.getName() + " Consecutive: " + savedProduct.getConsecutive());
                });
```

The above code creates both collections for me, but when I view the products, they all have consecutive number 1, and I also notice that it's the same value in the 'products_counter' collection.

Here is the output from the log at the end:

2023-05-24T09:17:57.918-05:00 INFO 8328 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-6] c.e.webflux.app.WebfluxApplication : Id: 646e1c955e0e0f2f68e2a120 Product: TV Panasonic Screen LCD Consecutive: 1 2023-05-24T09:17:57.975-05:00 INFO 8328 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] c.e.webflux.app.WebfluxApplication : Id: 646e1c955e0e0f2f68e2a121 Product: Apple iPod Consecutive: 1 2023-05-24T09:17:57.985-05:00 INFO 8328 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-4] c.e.webflux.app.WebfluxApplication : Id: 646e1c955e0e0f2f68e2a122 Product: Sony Notebook Consecutive: 1 2023-05-24T09:17:57.988-05:00 INFO 8328 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-5] c.e.webflux.app.WebfluxApplication : Id: 646e1c955e0e0f2f68e2a123 Product: Sony Camera HD Digital Consecutive: 1

What am I doing wrong?

I'm tryng to generate consecutive fields in mongodb in my products collection.

Comment: Probably cp1.setConsecutive(consecutive) returns a publisher, which you don't subscribe